# Network traffic

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

In my home, I have router and a computer which is connected via a cable to that router and a laptop via wireless. The problem is that when someone using the computer is accessing a Web service that allows viewing a remote camera from the place, the internet connection goes down (or becomes blocked) on my laptop. What would the cause of this? Internet traffic , bandwidth or that Web service? I have a speed of 120 Mbps.

Comment: These cameras wire or wireless?

Comment: Wire. These cameras are streaming the images over the internet and with that web service I can see what happen there. They also have something like a dvd-r (hard drive) where they store video . They are like security cameras or something like that .

Comment: So when somebody views the internal webserver for these camera your internet goes down?

Comment: Yup . My internet from the other computer or tablet or smartphone.

Comment: It sounds like a throughput problem.  What is the resolution of the video on these cameras?

Comment: From what I see in configuration pane(from the web service) the video resolution is CIF that means 352 × 288 rezolution , frame rate 25, bit rate type CBR, Bit rate Kb/s 1024 and I can see another label called Compression and it's H264 format .